# It it possible to have a relation $R$ on a set $A$ such that $R$ is reflexive, transitive, symmetric, and anti-symmetric?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basic set theory I know, I am just stumped on this. My intuition leads to think that it is not possible since if $R$ symmetric, and anti-symmetric then $R$ is not reflexive. But if $A=\emptyset$ then does this hold true?

Also one more quick question if there are two relations $M$ and $N$ that are both reflexive on relations on $A$ then is the relation $M \cap N $ reflexive? I believe it to be but is it possible to create reflexive relations some how that this does not hold? Hints/help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Basic set theory, you know. Yet you chose to ignore this very first thing you said when it came to tagging your question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yea sorry

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, a really nice example to consider is equality. It is reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, transitive, basically (almost) all you could which for, and it works for every set.

For your second question, yes, if $M$ and $N$ are reflexive relations on a set $A$, then of course also their intersection is reflexive. For that remember that $M \cap N$ contains exactly the elements that are contained in both $M$ and $N$. Which elements are surely both in $M$ and in $N$ if the relations are reflexive?

Comment: Aaaa okay thank-you, so if $A=\{1,2\}$ then if $R=\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ we have that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, transitive? I think I was misinterpreting the definition of anti-symmetric. And thank-you for confirmation on my last question:)